# Pi to the Nth Digit

Tags: beginner, objective-c, floating-point

I'm trying to teach myself Objective-C/Cocoa for eventual iPhone development but I figured I would start with a terminal app. It takes a user input, strips everything but numerics, then displays PI to the number that is left over.

Could anyone have a quick look over my code and see if there's any optimisations I could make or bad practises I could avoid?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        int i;
        char userInput[10];
        printf ("Enter a number: ");

        scanf("%s",userInput);
        NSString * number = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:userInput];

        NSString * strippedNumber = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [number length])];

        i = [strippedNumber intValue];

        printf("%d\n", i);
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("Enter a numeric character\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%.*f \n", M_PI, i);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW: I'm answering from a strong C perspective and weak Objective-C one

To avoid unexpected input and avoid string overflow:

```
//scanf("%s",userInput);
if (1 != scanf("%9s",userInput)) handle_error();
```

I'm sure you want:
[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761527/variable-interpolation-inside-printf-style-formatting-functions)

```
// printf("%.*f \n", M_PI, i);
printf("%.*f \n", i, M_PI);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply chux, In regards to the if statement, when i try it I get "Implicit declaration of function 'handle_error' is invalid in C99", Also with the printf that removes the formatting error i was getting, although the result was still the same as before which leaves me a bit confused.

Comment: I used scanf("%9s", userInput); so it only takes the first 9 digits and no more errors come up when I enter a  10+ String so thank you!

Comment: @Jacob2471 `handle_error()` is simple a random function name I made up to represent code you would write to handle the occurrence of bad input.

Comment: @Jacob2471 "removes the formatting error i was getting" and "the result ... same as before" are 2 things not in your post.  T'would be easier to assist if I knew what these 2 were.

Comment: I was getting a string format error, int cannot be assigned to float but swapping them around fixed it. What i meant by the results are the same as before was that no matter which way round the 'i' and the 'M_PI' was it would print PI to the 'i'th decimal place, I just found it strange that if they were the wrong way round why it wasn't printing i to the 'pi'th decimal place, which should be 'i' as it was an int. Also thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jacob2471 when you have the parameters in the wrong order, (let's assume a 4-byte `int` and 8-byte `double`), `printf()` took 4 bytes from `M_PI` (it was expecting an `int`) and tried to interpret that as a precision specification.  Then it took the remaining 4 bytes of `M_PI` concatenated with the 4-byte `i` to form _some_ `double`.  This is what _might_ have happed, but its Undefined Behavior, so other possibilities exist..

Comment: Ah i see, thank you very much. I can't +rep you right now but you deserve it.

Comment: @Jacob2471 When you hit 15+, I think up-vote ability kicks in.